# Change cursor in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mouse-cursor

I'm making a Windows Store app in C# and I have a normal *TextBlock* with a link inside it. And all I want to do it to make the cursor change into a hand when it goes over the text block, but unlike in WPF applications, there is no *Cursor* propriety. I know is a *CoreCursor* class in `Windows.UI.Core`. Am I suppose to use it somehow?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = 
    new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Hand, 1);
```

Comment: is there no way to do it through xaml

Answer (score 2):

WinRT XAML Toolkit has an attached property that works just about the same as the `Cursor` property in WPF in that you set a cursor for an element and so when your mouse cursor hovers on top of that element - the cursor changes to what the property specifies and when it leaves control bounds - it restores the previous cursor. There are actually two properties - one called [`FrameworkElementExtensions.SystemCursor`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/FrameworkElementExtensions.cs) that takes any standard cursor from the [CoreCursorType enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corecursortype.aspx), which you just use like in [this sample page](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample.Windows/Views/Controls.Extensions/ControlExtensionsCursorTestPage.xaml) - set

```
<Border
    xmlns:Extensions="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions"
    Extensions:FrameworkElementExtensions.SystemCursor="Cross"/>
```

The other one - [`FrameworkElementExtensions.Cursor`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/FrameworkElementExtensions.cs) allows you to set any custom cursor, but I believe you'd need to set it in code behind like `FrameworkElementExtensions.SetCursor(myElement, myCursor);` or bind to a cursor property set elsewhere.

You can also use custom cursors. You need to define a cursor in a native resource library as described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2012/08/02/customcursors-in-windows-8-csharp-metro-applications.aspx) and then you should be able to set them either globally by setting the `Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor` property or with an attached property like my [`FrameworkElementExtensions.Cursor`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/FrameworkElementExtensions.cs).