# On cursor Progress Ring for UWP/C#

Tags: c#, uwp, progress

I am wondering if anybody has information on how to switch my cursor to a progress ring while I am waiting for a new window to launch within my uwp app. I've seen the documentation for the Progress Ring/Bar classes, and I can't see an obvious way to attach the control to my cursor instead of using a static progress ring. Any suggestions are helpful! Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change cursor in Windows Store Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472202/change-cursor-in-windows-store-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See duplicate, but:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = 
    new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Wait , 1);
```

Note that the "ring" is just an OS representation of the state and might change over time.